# connection between NSManagedObjectModel and my .xcdatamodel file?

Tags: core-data

Archiving is easy, now concepts of CoreData are confusing me.

What's the connection between the declared NSManagedObjectModel and my actual xcdatamodel file?

I declared NSManagedObjectModel, NSManagedObjectContext and accordingly a NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, and connected all three of them. During this process, I didn't see any clue that the declared NSManagedObjectModel property had anything to do with my xcdatamodel file.

Only when I initiated a NSFetchRequest, I told it the name of my targeted entity, and which was my NSManagedObjectContext.

And that'll do it? I don't have to tell anyone the name of my xcdatamodel file, but only the name of the targeted entity? Does the NSFetchRequest have to search all my xcdatamodel files for the certain entity? What if I have two entities of same name in two different xcdatamodel?

Comment: Please read the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075). Core Data is very complex, it is not something you just can learn in a day. If you want to save yourself headache in future read the documentation. Believe me, it will do you good.

Comment: Nothing is magic, though it may appear so sometimes. Show the code you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your app, the `.xcdatamodel` file is compiled to produce a `.mom` file, which is incorporated into the app bundle.  The prefix remains unchanged so, "myApplication.xcdatamodel" is compiled to "myApplication.mom".

If you get the URL for this file in the bundle (for example using `NSBundle`'s `URLForResource:withExtension` method) you can initialise your `NSManagedObjectModel` instance using `initWithContentsOfURL`.  Alternatively, and this may explain the apparent absence of any connection, the  `NSManagedObjectModel` instance can be created using `mergedModelFromBundles` class method, which uses ALL the models (`.mom` files) in the given bundle.

Comment: Thanks.  that perfectly answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

The `NSManagedObjectModel` is the object that represents the entities you create in the data model (the `.xcdatamodeld`). The data model editor is sort of like a source code editor, while the `NSManagedObjectModel` is the thing you have that represents the compiled model.

The `NSManagedObjectModel` contains references to all of the entities in the model, which are represented as instances of `NSEntityDescription`. The purpose of the model object is

1. So that Core Data can understand the persistent store file. The model tells Core Data what entities to expect.
2. So that Core Data operations like fetch requests can be configured to properly access the persistent store file-- only using entities that actually exist there, for example.
3. So that instances of `NSManagedObject` can be created to reflect entities from the data model.